# Issue when loading an ico from a Qt resource file

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-designer

I am using Qt Designer 4.8.4 and I include two files in the QMainWindow resource file: a .ico file and a .gif file. When loading from code using:

```
QPixmap p;
p.load(":/MyApp/media/logo.gif");  // does work
p.load(":/MyApp/media/logo.ico");  // does not work
```

The gif file works, but not the ico file. **Is there any reason?** I am using the ico file as the window icon and it is not showing when running the application.

And, YES, I am successfully compiling the qrc file since the **GIF file is working**.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*.ico is not supported.

By default, Qt supports the following formats:

Format  Description Qt's support

BMP Windows Bitmap  Read/write

GIF Graphic Interchange Format (optional)   Read

JPG Joint Photographic Experts Group    Read/write

JPEG    Joint Photographic Experts Group    Read/write

PNG Portable Network Graphics   Read/write

PBM Portable Bitmap Read

PGM Portable Graymap    Read

PPM Portable Pixmap Read/write

TIFF    Tagged Image File Format    Read/write

XBM X11 Bitmap  Read/write

XPM X11 Pixmap  Read/write

Comment: Thanks four your reply. The problem is that Qt Designer lets me add icons file to the resource file, and then the Qt Designer previewer shows the icon as a window icon. This is quite confusing. Thanks,

Comment: Note that this information is misleading now. Qt can open `ico` files since version 4.4; as of version 5.4, the list also includes `tga`, `dds`, `webp`, `jpeg2000`, `mng` and others (as found in the qtimageformats repository).

Answer (score 3):

Because QPixmap Cant read .ico files simply, 
take a look at documentation [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpixmap.html) if you want to know more about formats supported

Comment: The link is dead. Content moved to: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer here is incorrect, or as mentioned in the comments, at least misleading.  Qt has come with a plugin for handling ICO format since sometime in version 4.4.  Here's a [similar question](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55254-setWindowIcon()-with-ICO-format?p=247149#post247149) from the same era.

For deployment, one needs to copy the `plugins/imageformats/[lib]qico.[dll|so]` file from the Qt installation used for building with to within their executable's directory. Put it in a subfolder, like so: `<your_executable>/imageformats/qico.dll`. If testing a debug build, the `d` suffix version of the lib is needed instead (`qicod.dll`).

([This newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515996/the-icon-does-not-load-when-you-start-the-application-from-the-outside-qt-creato?noredirect=1&lq=1) has been marked as a duplicate of this, so now 2 questions point to the wrong answer. Which is why I'm essentially repeating my post here.)

Answer (score 2):

you can convert it's format to Qt supported formats.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your followup on the already chosen answer, you may want to have that ICO as the appwindow icon. That is possible, and also is perhaps why Qt Designer is capable of displaying  it (trying to guess your intent). However, having it so doesn't involve any QPixmap coding, it's purely configuration affair. Described here (and yes, #worksforme) :

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/appicon.html

Comment: This also is now available on: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/appicon.html :‌[