# QPixmap parse ico image file that does't show

Tags: qt, qt5, qpixmap

I use QPixmap parse ico image file and set qpixmap object to QLabel whit setPixmap function，but doesn't show ico image.

```
ico_label_ = new QLabel(this);
ico_label_->move(100, 100);
QPixmap pixmap(":/client/test.ico");
Q_ASSERT(!pixmap.isNull());
ico_label_->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

With Q_ASSERT checking pixmap is valid.
please help me how to do that ico image file can show on QLabel

Since stackoverflow can't upload ico file and the ico file see [test ico file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr5xd6qh29kegeq/test.ico?dl=0)

Comment: Think you,but your surggestion , I had done before ask help. you can download  ico file that I used

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue when loading an ico from a Qt resource file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456683/issue-when-loading-an-ico-from-a-qt-resource-file)

Comment: QPixmap support some ico file，I think the qico plugin bug

Comment: I can't see that icon using a number of programs on Linux. Please file a bugreport against Qt, and just use png as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon you've provided seems to be not valid. (At least the file I've downloaded from the Drop-Box)

This project demonstrates that .ico in Qt4/5 work (tested with both)

https://github.com/vheinitz/QIconTest

- Show Icon 1: attempts to display your icon (fails)
- Show Icon 2: attempts to display other icon (works)

Often issues with not displayed icons (or other image formats) occurs due to
missing (or not found at run-time) plugins.

Make sure, you include required plugins in your installation and set the path at the run time to the plugin location e.g.:

```
qApp->addLibraryPath(qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/plugins");
```