# The icon does not load when you start the application from the outside Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qicon

I have a *.ico file.

The icon is loaded by the setWindowIcon() function. I added a *.ico file to the resource file. 
When I launch the application from Qt Creator, the icon is displayed correctly.
But when I launch the application from outside Qt Creator, the icon is not displayed. The application successfully starts and works, but the icon is not displayed.

```
this->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icon/MiniAMR.ico")); // OK, icon load (inside Qt)

/* this string in .pro-file */
RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc
```

Please, help.

Comment: This is weird. The first thing I'd check is if the program you launch from Qt Creator is the same than the one you launch directly. It could be that Q Creator is building in the release directory, while you are launching an old version from the debug directory. If that's not it, try to add some debug output (`qDebug()`) to check if the ico file is available at run-time.

Comment: @BenjaminT, I partially fixed this trouble. I added to .pro-file follow string: 
win32:RC_ICONS = MiniAMR.ico
and this is works!
But I want use this picture in other places in my code. For example, I want display picture in widget:
    QPixmap pix(":/icon/MiniAMR.ico");
    ui->label_pic->setPixmap(pix);
and this not worked :(

Comment: `RC_ICONS` is for the icon of the executable. This is handled by Windows, not by Qt, `qmake` will just pass the value to the linker when the executable file is created. On the other hand when you display an image in the user interface, then this is Qt doing the work. However, Qt does not support `ico` files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456683/issue-when-loading-an-ico-from-a-qt-resource-file adn https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats

Comment: I'd say the fact that the `ico` works at all seems to suggest the format is indeed supported...  :)  I don't know why the QImage docs don't mention ICO format, maybe because a plugin is required, but that plugin has been part of Qt for a long time. I wouldn't personally use ICO for much except the RC icon.

Comment: Thanks all for a recommendations.
I changed .ico-file to .png-file, and this works for a loading to QLabel.
To upload the icon, I left the previous version with win32:RC_ICONS = MiniAMR.ico in .pro-file

Comment: @BenjaminT I agree this is a similar question to the one you duped it as, but that answer is wrong (see my previous comment here). The answer already has a comment on it about it being wrong (or at least misleading). Do you have a recommendation as to best course of action?

Comment: @Konstantin Did you try my proposed solution also by any chance? It might be useful for anyone else who comes along and finds this Q/A.

Comment: @Konstantin I have voted to reopen the question, since it is not exactly the same and the question I linked has a false answer.

Comment: @Konstantin Please look at the `supportedImageFormat()` function, it will tell you at run-time what are the image format plugins that are loaded. If you find any difference, that means that you are missing plugins (in this case `qico.dll`). The easiest way to solve this kind of problem is to use `windeployqt`.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to copy the `plugins/imageformats/qico.dll` file from the Qt installation you're building with to within your executable's directory. Put it in a subfolder, like so: `<your_executable>/imageformats/qico.dll`. If testing a debug build, you'll need the `d` suffix version of the dll (`qicod.dll`).

When run from QtCreator, it sets up the correct environment variables so that your application knows where to find the Qt plugins. When run outside of QtCreator, your app probably can't find the plugin.

Comment: You are right, but the correct solution is to use `windeployqt`. Not only it will copy `qico.dll`, it will also patch `Qt5Core.dll` to make it search plugin in the correct subfolder. Also it will deploy all the plugins that the application may need.

Comment: @BenjaminT `windeployqt` is a whole other issue. My answer addresses the particular need in this question (or at least tries to, we don't know w/out the OP actually trying it). And no it is not *necessary* to use `windeployqt`, I've deployed quite a few Qt apps w/out it, nor is it necessary to patch anything in order to deploy a Qt app on Windows. Furthermore it tends to copy a bunch of stuff you don't actually need to deploy an app. So, if one knows what they're doing, it's actually better to do those steps "manually" (or script them yourself). This is all way out of scope of this Q/A.

Comment: It is not *necessary* to use `windeployqt` to deploy Qt libraries, but it is the easiest and officially documented way, plugin ans qml dependencies. Yes, it ends up deploying more than what you need as it deploys everything that might be needed ans thus prevents this kinds of error where people forgot a plugin.

Comment: Last point, it is necessary to patch `Qt5Core.dll` as its installation path is hardcoded withing itself (e.g. `qt_prfxpath=C:\Qt\5.12.2\mingw73_64`). `windeployqt` will change this to `qt_prfxpath=.`. Not doing it can create further issues. And the fact that you have deploy a lot of Qt apps w/o patching and it worked, does not mean that you are doing the right thing. Other people had  and still have issues when not doing it.